# How do I get the current sequence number in an iteration in F#?

Tags: f#, iteration, sequence

Consider the following code to demonstrate the question:

```
let sequence = Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> "Element")
Seq.iter (fun _ -> printf "Element no: ?") sequence
```

Is it in any way possible to get the current sequence number (e.g. its rank) to print?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the **iteri** function:

```
let sequence = Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> "Element")
sequence |> Seq.iteri (fun i _ -> printfn "Element no. %d" i)
```